# Can anybody tell me how to hide my MAC address of my PC from hackers, spammer and bad neighbour sites?

Tags: mac-address

Can anybody help me to hide my MAC address of my machine from hackers and spammers etc?

Also are there any other things that I should hide from hackers? I have hidden my IP address already but is there anything more than these two things I can hide?

OS: Windows XP

Comment: Hackers can't see your MAC address unless they have access to your network or you're sending it out to the internet. Learning how ARP works should clarify that.

Comment: I saw your other questions regarding changing your IP every 4 seconds, and you're still hung up on this "[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"  There are lots of ways to get better security while online, but changing IPs and spoofing MAC addresses isn't likely necessary for most internet users.  You'd be better off focusing on avoiding phishing attacks, using good passwords, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant hide your MAC Adress. The MAC Adress is used for the router (technically it is the switch part of your dsl box) to know which computer to talk to. Since the router part of your dsl box uses IP Adresses and also uses NAT (Network Adress Translation), the MAC Adress cannot be seen from the outer world. Also security by obscurity is not effective. Just increase the host security by uninstalling xp and using windows 7 for examlple or linux.

Comment: i didnt say this did i? and i know you can fake them. but the MAC adress is used on Layer 2 to talk to the dsl router. hide != spoof

Comment: "Hiding" is effectively spoofing.